# how to add event in ipod ical from ios 5 application?

Tags: iphone

every one i am using EKEventStore to add events into iphone calender from my app, its working for the devices of ios version 4.2, and from my application the events are added into ical perfectly but when i installed the same app in ipod with ios version 5, strangely the events are not adding into ical, here is my function to add the events,

```
    -(void)icall_add{


 //daily_trackAppDelegate *controller2 =(daily_trackAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    event.title     = text2.text;
    //event.attendees = controller2.who;
    event.notes= text3.text;


    //controller2.new_event_title = @"";
    //controller2.new_recent_location = @"";


    event.startDate = mydatepicker.date;
    //event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:3600 sinceDate:event.startDate];
    event.endDate = mydatepicker.date;

    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
    NSError *err;
    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];  
    daily_trackAppDelegate *controller2 =(daily_trackAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    text1.text = @"";
    text2.text = @"";
    text3.text = @"";
    controller2.who = @"";
    controller2.new_event_title = @"";
    controller2.new_recent_location = @"";



}
```

please guide what is that problem n how to solve it, thanx in advance, Regards Saad.

Answer (score 1):

Easy fix, just go to Settings> iCloud > Turn on Calendars
PROBLEM FIXED!!